# Web Browser Filter

Tags: vb.net, web, browser

I would like to have a list of websites (each on a different line) that the web browser will check when navigated and if it is the current url then it will navigate back. Below is some code that I have currently have created and fails because it doesn't check each line of text and below that is some code that also check text with current text.

```
Using sr As New StreamReader("website_lists.txt")
        Dim lined As String
        lined = sr.ReadToEnd()
        Dim scanbox As New TextBox
        scanbox.Multiline = True
        Dim buff As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        For Each line In lined
            If TextBox1.Text.Contains(scanbox.Text) Then
                webview.GoBack()
                MsgBox("Infected website! For your own sake stay away!")
            End If
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Some code that kinda does the same thing:

```
Dim md5 As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
            Dim f As FileStream = New FileStream(ListBox1.SelectedItem, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8192)
            f = New FileStream(ListBox1.SelectedItem, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8192)
            md5.ComputeHash(f)
            Dim hash As Byte() = md5.Hash
            Dim buff As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
            Dim hashByte As Byte
            For Each hashByte In hash
                buff.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", hashByte))
            Next

            If scanbox.Text.Contains(buff.ToString) Then
```

Have any suggestions or help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `File.Readlines`... More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on this method. Also your declaring a new textbox but the text is never set which means the contains wont work... Another suggestion, turn Option Strict On its your friend.

```
' Loop over lines in file.
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("yourfile")
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains(line) Then
            webview.GoBack()
            MsgBox("Infected website! For your own sake stay away!")
            Exit For
        End If
Next
```